# Windows Remote Desktop Services. Disable mouse and keyboard

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

Is there any way to disable Mouse and Keyboard functions in a Remote Desktop Connection?

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2. I checked the Group Policies but didn't find anything related.

**I just want to allow Remote Desktop connection without mouse/keyboard functions (spectator mode)**

Comment: How would that actually work? The user would just stare at the desktop? For what purpose would you want to accomplish this?

Comment: It's a financial real time app showing for some users. We don't have and API right know to show it in another location, so, We were looking for a temporal way to show the data but restricting access to the app functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Remote Desktop is designed for remote access, not for screen sharing. How can a user ever log out if they can't use the keyboard or mouse? This will leave countless sessions open and running in the background. You want a different product for this, not RDP.

Even if you could do this, each RDP connection opens a new, independent session to the server. Something that you do in your session will not be visible to someone else that's logged in, as your sessions would be isolated. This would defeat the purpose of using this as a presentation tool. No one could see what you were doing.

Perhaps something like [WebEx](http://www.webex.com) or [GoToMeeting](http://www.gotomeeting.com/) might be more appropriate. You can also configure [UltraVNC Server](http://www.uvnc.com/install/configuration.html) (and probably other VNC variants) to ignore remote user input.